# DropDownlist PostBack Looses Selected Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-files, postback

I have a dropdownlist that load all the list items from a text file, it contains a list of printer name,description,ipaddress and connection string id. so I display to the user the printer name-description and when the user selects the printer the values I pass is either the ip address or connection string depending on the situation.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   LoadPrinterList();
  }
protected void LoadPrinterList()
 {
 string CSVFilePathName = 
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
 string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
 string[] Fields;
 Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
 int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 //1st row must be column names; 
 //force lower case to ensure matching later on.
 for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
 dt.Columns.Add(Fields[i].ToLower(), typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("nameanddescription", 
 typeof(string), "name +'-'+ description");
 dt.Columns.Add("ipandconnectionstring", 
 typeof(string), "ip +'-'+ ConncetionStringID");
 DataRow Row;
 for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
 {
  Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
  Row = dt.NewRow();
  for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
  Row[f] = Fields[f];
  dt.Rows.Add(Row);
  }
   string hostname = Request.UserHostName.Substring(0, 3);
   string[] name = Printerlist.SelectedValue.Split('-');
   //string plant = name[0].ToString();
   //string plantvalue = plant.Substring(0, 3);
   //if(hostname == plantvalue)
   //{
   Printerlist.DataTextField = "nameanddescription";
   Printerlist.DataValueField = "ipandconnectionstring";
   //}
   Printerlist.DataSource = dt;
   Printerlist.DataBind();
}
```

[What the user sees first as an option for the printer list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAVaK.jpg)

when the user click the drop down they see this:

[when drop down is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPyVg.jpg)

so now the user selects a printer so selected index is > 0 so based on that I do the following in code behind.

```
protected void Printerlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
   }
  else
  {

   if (Printerlist.SelectedItem.Text.Length > 0)
    {
    TxtItem.Focus();
    }
   else
    {
    TxtItem.Text = string.Empty;
    TxtQty.Text = string.Empty;
    DropDownList2.SelectedIndex = 0;
    lbldesc.Visible = false;
    //TxtBase.Text = string.Empty;
    //TxtBase1.Text = string.Empty;
    bestbeforewillbe.Text = string.Empty;
    TxtBestBeforeMonths.Text = string.Empty;
    TxtRotcode.Text = string.Empty;
    zplcode.Text = string.Empty;
    string message = "The selected printer is
    not a local printer";
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = 
    new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
    sb.Append("alert('");
    sb.Append(message);
    sb.Append("')};");
    sb.Append("</script>");
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
   (this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
  }

 }
```

}

this is the dropdownlist values in my aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Printerlist" runat="server"
 Height="16px" Width="268px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Printerlist_SelectedIndexChanged" OnTextChanged="Printerlist_TextChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I have EnableViewState=true; but that didn't help either.

**plese help I cant seem to figure out, every time the user selects a value there is a postback and after the postback "-" is selected as the printer value.**

Comment: I hate this....  if (!Page.IsPostBack) { } else { //do stuff }... why not just  if (Page.IsPostBack) { //do stuff }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check `ISPOSTBACK` on page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack) 
   LoadPrinterList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Bud

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly check if a `PostBack` occurred, otherwise any time that your `Page_Load` method is being triggered, it is repopulating your controls with their initial data (i.e. you are losing your changes there).

You simply need to add an if-statement and only execute your `LoadPrinterList()` method if it is an initial load :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
        // Only perform this on the initial load
        LoadPrinterList();
   }
}
```

Additionally, you shouldn't need a similar check within your `Printerlist_SelectedIndexChanged` event as the event is going to be triggered from within the page (i.e. after it has already been loaded), so that statement should never evaluate as true.

Comment: oh yup your right I was checking if it was a post back for each control, your method work much better, thanks bud